# Decode BLE Glucometer characteristics value

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, bluetooth-lowenergy, arraybuffer

I am using a BLE device to read glucose value and get it on my system, but
I am stuck on how to parse the encoded value returning from the glucometer characteristics value.

for eg: I am getting `[27, 15, 0, 232, 7, 1, 30, 5, 58, 27, 83, 1, 111, 176, 248, 0, 0]` in response from the BLE device, and I am supposed to convert it to exactly `6.2`.

example of another reading:

Characteristics value: `[27, 13, 0, 232, 7, 1, 29, 11, 21, 52, 83, 1, 115, 176, 248, 0, 0]`     Device Reading: 6.4

BLE device used: Accucheck Glucometer

[Documentation Link](https://innoveit.github.io/react-native-ble-manager/events/#blemanagerdidupdatevalueforcharacteristic) - using this we got the above array, but unable to decode to a particular device value.
a code snippet i tried - https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-vxbwzb?file=index.js

So, need help to find out the correlation between the required glucose value and the encoded value being sent from the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const bits = [27, 15, 0, 232, 7, 1, 30, 5, 58, 27, 83, 1, 111, 176, 248, 0, 0];
console.log((bits[12]/18).toFixed(1))
```

In array we are getting value at 12th bit in mg/dl unit. Then we can convert it to mmol/l by dividing it with 18. Then we can get the answer in mmol/l